# java threads : producer - consumer 

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I have some developpements to do and I try to see if there is a desing pattern to use.
The problem is simple:

I have a main thread that launches many treads. The main thread must wait for each thread to finish and then doing something else.
The existing code it's a bit ugly. I have a while loop that check a thread group to see if is something running:

```
//launch threads
.....
//wait for threads to finish
while (ThreadRepository.getInstance().isActiveThreadGroup(myGroupId)) {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}

//doing something else
```

So, as you see, the while loop keeps running  until no threads running.

I was thinking at the pattern producer-consumer and I would like to do something like that:

Using some BlockingQueue for instance, and each thread put (or take)  something in it.
Instead of having the while and sleep I would like to have something like 
`myQueue.take()` but something to wait for the queue to be empty.
When empty, it means no threads running.

I try to search on the Internet but I did not found something that matches my problem.

Does anyone know the most efficient to solve my problem ?

Comment: If the number of theads were fixed in advance, you could use the `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: Marko, what do you mean by "without returning the contributors' favor" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two easy ways to have one thread wait for N threads to finish:

1. Make the main thread call join() on all the other threads. join() returns when a thread finishes, or has already finished
2. Create a CountDownLatch initialized to N, pass this latch to all the threads, make each thread call `countDown()` on the latch when it has finished, and make the main thread call `await()` on the latch. This second technique is a bit harder than the first one, but is also more flexible and reusable, and allows being awaken after some delay, even if the N threads have not finished yet.

Comment: Thanks. I did not knew this class. It exactly what I need. I've tested, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BlockingQueue as follows:

- each child thread puts a message in the queue when finished
- the main thread takes messages from the queue and counts them. When the number of messages equals the number of threads, all threads has finished.